# Where Windows 7 store date/time shown in Windows Live Mail 'Sent' folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, date-time, windows-live-mail

Windows 7: where Windows store date/time shown in list of sent emails in **Windows Live Mail** 'Sent' folder? When highlight Sent folder, right side show list of sent emails, 3rd column is 'Sent' column, that show message Date/Time. Where does the date/time values come from, where it stored?